# How can I access value table entries of signals in CAPL?

Tags: testcase, capl, canoe

I'm building CAPL test cases, and when the test passes, I want to output a signal (Status P) description based on current value . a table in signal:

| Value | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 0*0 | OFF |
| 0*1 | INIT |
| 0*2 | IDEAL |
| 0*3 | ACTIVE |
| 0*4 | Error |

i have tried this

```
if(Failure  == 0)
  {
    snprintf (msg, 200, "%s","");
    snprintf (buffer, 200, "%s", "It has NO ERROR, It is in ");
    strncat (msg, buffer,40);
    snprintf (buffer, 200, "%d", $Status_P);
    testStepPass("",msg);
```

it is not printing values or description. could you please help me?

Comment: This seems a very weird way to build a string, and I don't know what `$Status_P` is meant to be, but you can just use `snprintf()` to build it in one go, i.e. something like: `snprintf(msg, 200, "It has NO ERROR, It is in %s", Status_P);` (Assuming `Status_P` is a nul-terminated string.)

Comment: thank you. Status_P is the name of the signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the description for a signal value by using the CAPL function `getSignalDescriptionForValue`.

Usage is as follows:

```
char buffer[50];
long retVal;

retVal = getSignalDescriptionForValue(Node::Message::Signal, <raw signal value>, buffer, elcount(buffer));
```

`Node::Message::Signal` has to be the signal itself, i.e. the thing you get, when you drag&drop the signal from the Symbols pane into your code in the CAPL Browser.

`<raw signal value>` has to be the raw value (not the physical value) of the signal, in your case most likely `$Signal_P.raw` unless there is an ambiguity in the signal name.

`buffer` will contain the description `retVal` can be used for error checking

Comment: thank you for your answer but It is not printing any Description. it is shwoing null.

Comment: @K.Stefan what is the value of `retVal`?

Comment: retVal is showing "null" while signal is showing "IDEAL"

Comment: @K.Stefan `retVal` is a long. That cannot be null.

Comment: Thank you,  it is working. i was printing retVal instaed of buffer.